# said: 550 5.1.1 no such local recipient: <auth-results@verifier.port25.com>?

Tags: email, postfix

I try to verify my config for my domain, but when I send mail to `auth-results@verifier.port25.com` there is this error :

```
his is the mail system at host MY_DOMAIN.fr.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                   The mail system

<auth-results@verifier.port25.com>: host verifier.port25.com[38.95.177.125]
    said: 550 5.1.1 no such local recipient: <auth-results@verifier.port25.com>
    in "RCPT TO:<auth-results@verifier.port25.com>
    ORCPT=rfc822;auth-results@verifier.port25.com" (in reply to RCPT TO
    command)

Reporting-MTA: dns; MY_DOMAIN.fr
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 5A37A240C13
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; contact@MY_DOMAIN.fr
Arrival-Date: Thu, 21 Jul 2016 12:24:31 +0200 (CEST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; auth-results@verifier.port25.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Remote-MTA: dns; verifier.port25.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 5.1.1 no such local recipient:
    <auth-results@verifier.port25.com> in "RCPT
    TO:<auth-results@verifier.port25.com>
    ORCPT=rfc822;auth-results@verifier.port25.com"
```

But, if send mail to my yahoo mail for exemple, there is no problem... So what's wrong with port25?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send an email to `check-auth@verifier.port25.com` instead of `auth-results@verifier.port25.com`.